# JPA Criteria API causing missing right parenthesis error

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following Expression to concatenate two columns

```
Expression<String> stringConcat = 
criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.concat(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc), " # "), 
rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.empNo));
```

and it used in CriteriQuery in the followng manner,

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.userId), 
root.get(ProductCatalogue_.productList),criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
.when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.prodId),"ZCX"), stringConcat)
.otherwise(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc)));
```

However when SQL is generated, it is throwing error

> missing right parenthesis

because in `if else` part of SQL has a question mark as it is expecting a parameter

```
THEN (t0.prodDesc = ?)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: why not present the full SQL generated for that criteria query rather than some snapshot. And then mention which JPA provider. And then if it is generating incorrect SQL then raise a bug with your JPA provider (they all have bugs and need to know about such things)

Comment: and ProductEmp_ ... how is that relating to the candidate entity? and where is the join to it? To verify if it is the "concat" causing the problem ... just do a Criteria query selecting the "concat" and see if it puts this parameter in there

Comment: rootEmp is what? Can't comment on that concat without knowing what it is. As also said ... try a basic criteria query with JUST the concat as a select clause, to test the concat only (i.e no CASE)

Comment: @NeilStockton Without `case` statement `concat` works well. When case is added, it throws error.

Comment: so report a bug with your JPA provider

Comment: And show the full query, as it looks like your 'then' statement isn't the only problem unless ProductList_.prodDesc is equivalent to t0.prod_id.  If your stringConcat works, what does it generate if it is in the select clause by itself instead of the case statement with the otherwise statement?

Comment: That shows the problem SQL, not the SQL you said works when the case statement is removed.  I am curious if EclipseLink was handling the stringConcat and rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc)) expressions correctly outside of the case, and what it generated for them.

Comment: Which EclipseLink version are you using? [There was a bug exactly on this issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381250), fixed in 2.4.2 version. I could test the very same code in 2.5.2 and works fine.

Comment: @perissf Spot on and great, I changed my jar version to 2.5.2, thus problem solved. If you could post an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks for your help in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [is an EclipseLink bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381250), that was fixed in version 2.4.2.
Upgrade to a newer version, and it will work (tested on EclipseLink 2.5.2).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I upgraded to EclipseLink 2.5.2 version and it error disappeared. Much appreciated.